# How Do I store a number with a comma in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have to compare large lists of amounts to a proprietary system that does not match the amount if it does not have a comma i.e. 1,000 <> 1000.

For the life of me I cant get my VBA code to capture the commas in the amounts.

I have tried storing Amount as Double, String, Number, currency and no luck

```
With ws.Range("C:C")
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
End With

and

Amount = CDbl(ws.Cells(2, 3))
```

I also tried splitting the number i pull from the system at the , but it got really messy when I had to code it for numbers over 10 mill so i scraped it.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly helpful

Comment: Have you tried formatting the column C number style before your attempts? Or maybe you can do a search and replace function on the commas coming from the proprietary system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on a cell.....if you see **1,234.56** in the cell and **1234.56** in the formula bar and you want VBA to get the "as formatted"" value, then:

```
Sub WYSIWYG()
    Dim st As String
    st = ActiveCell.Text
End Sub
```

will retrieve the value, complete with the comma.

Comment: I didnt know I could capture via .text this is perfect thanks man

Answer (score 0):

You could import the data and strip out the commas before comparison. This will remove any commas and then force the cell to convert to a number before comparison.

```
=((SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")*-1)*-1) <> B1
```